How to print name nested functions?
For example, we have this:
def function_one():
    print("Function one")
    def function_two():
        print("Function two")
        def function_three():
            print("Function three")

And wee need to see this:
(function_one, function_two, function_three)

I tryed ast library, but it shows only first layer of function.

The inner print statements are not called by defining the function but by executing them. So inside function_one there has to be a line of function_two() and function_three(). However, this will print seperate lines, to print in the same take a look at the end parameter of print

The AST contains all the information  you need.  What exactly did you try?

Also take a look at this question

OP's requested output isn't related to what the functions would output when called.

Using functionality provided by the ast module we can get the required output as follows:
from ast import parse, walk, FunctionDef
from inspect import getsource

def function_one():
    print("Function one")
    def function_two():
        print("Function two")
        def function_three():
            print("Function three")

def getfuncs(func): 
    for n in walk(parse(getsource(func))):
        if isinstance(n, FunctionDef):
            yield n.name

print("(" + ", ".join(getfuncs(function_one)) + ")")

Output:
(function_one, function_two, function_three)


Took the answer from this example:
import ast, inspect

# this is the test scenario
def function1():
    f1_var1 = 42
    def function2():
        f2_var1 = 42
        f2_var2 = 42
        def function3():
            f3_var1 = 42

# derive source code for top-level function
src = inspect.getsource(function1)

# derive abstract syntax tree rooted at top-level function
node = ast.parse(src)

# next, ast's walk method takes all the difficulty out of tree-traversal for us
for x in ast.walk(node):
    # functions have names whereas variables have ids,
    # nested-classes may all use different terminology
    # you'll have to look at the various node-types to
    # get this part exactly right
    name_or_id = getattr(x,'name', getattr(x,'id',None))
    if name_or_id:
        print name_or_id

Response:
function1
function2
f1_var1
function3
f2_var1
f2_var2
f3_var1

Thank you!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
